# MS Access Time Overlapping Validation VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, time, overlapping

I'm trying to setup a time validation to prevent overlapping in MS Access.

I tried code from other forms of overlapping but I can't quite figure it out.
The form setup has a field box for Operator (operator enters name),  Operator_Start (the operator enters start time and date), Operator_End (The operator enters end time and date).

All information goes to a table named tbl_ActiveOperators

```
If DCount("*", "[tbl_ActiveOperators]", "[Operator_Start] <= Forms!frm_Job_Details.Operator_End And [Operator_End] >= Forms!frm_Job_Details.Operator_Start And [Operator] ") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error:  Times overlap"
    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If
```

The error I receive is: run-time error 2471: the expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Forms!frm_Job_Details.Operator_End'

Here's more of the code I currently have.  Everything seems to work except for the Time Overlap message box.

```
Private Sub Operator_Start_AfterUpdate()
If Process_Worktype <> "Reconciliation" Then
    If Me.Process_Worktype.Value = "Administration NB" Then
        Me.Operator_Start.Value = dhRoundTime([Operator_Start], 5)
        Else
        Me.Operator_Start.Value = RoundTime([Operator_Start])
    End If
End If

If (Operator_Start < Forms!frm_Job_Details.[In Time]) Then
MsgBox "Error, Your Start Time cannot be before your Job In Time"
Me.Operator_Start = Forms!frm_Job_Details.[In Time]
Me.Comments.SetFocus
Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If (Operator_Start > Forms!frm_Job_Details.[Deadline]) Then
MsgBox "Error, Your Start Time cannot be after your Job Deadline"
Me.Operator_Start = Forms!frm_Job_Details.[Deadline]
Me.Comments.SetFocus
Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If (Process_Worktype <> "Reconciliation" And Operator_Start > Operator_End) Or (Len(Nz(Process_Worktype, "")) = 0 And Operator_Start > Operator_End) Then
MsgBox "Error, Your start time cannot be later than your deadline unless this is a Reconciliation"
Me.Comments.SetFocus
Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
End If

If (Operator_Start = Operator_End) Then
MsgBox "Alert! Your start time is the same as end time. No Time billed."
Me.Comments.SetFocus
Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
End If

'validation for overlap time
'If (Operator_Start > Operator_Start And Operator_Start < Operator_End) Then
'    If DLookup("Operator_Start", "tbl_ActiveOperators", Me.Operator = "Operator") Then
'    MsgBox "HI"
'    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
'    Cancel = True
'    End If
'End If

'If (Operator_Start > Operator_Start And Operator_Start < Operator_End) Then
'    DLookup("Operator_Start", "tbl_ActiveOperators", Me.Operator = "Operator") Then
'    MsgBox "HI"
'    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
'    Cancel = True
'End If

'If DCount("*", "tbl_ActiveOperators", "Operator_Start < Forms!frm_Job_Details.[Operator_End] And Operator_End > Forms!frm_Job_Details.[Operator_Start] And Operator = Forms!frm_Job_Details.[Operator] ") > 0 Then
'    MsgBox "Error:  Times overlap"
'    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
'    Cancel = True
'End If


If DCount("*", "[tbl_ActiveOperators]", "[Operator_Start] <= Forms!frm_Job_Details!Operator_End And [Operator_End] >= Forms!frm_Job_Details!Operator_Start And Not [Operator] Is Null ") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error:  Times overlap"
    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This bit at the end looks wrong: `And [Operator]`. Maybe substitute `And Not [Operator] Is Null`

Comment: Hi Kismert, thanks for the reply.  I'm still receiving the same error message after making that change.   run-time error 2471: the expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Forms!frm_Job_Details.Operator_End'

Comment: Instead of a `.` before the control references, try `!`, like so: `Forms!frm_Job_Details!Operator_End` and `Forms!frm_Job_Details!Operator_Start`

Comment: Hi Kismert,  I applied the changes you recommended and the error message went away, but i'm not a message box when times overlap.  Should I be applying the changes to the Form_BeforeUpdate or Operator_Start_BeforeUpdate or Operator_End_BeforeUpdate?  Right now I'm applying changes to the Operator_Start_BeforeUpdate.

Comment: I've added more of the VBA above, just in case.

Comment: In general, Use `BeforeUpdate` for validation (is the data correct?). Use `Cancel = True` to make the user fix the problem, or abandon changes. At least, use `Form_BeforeUpdate` to ensure the whole record is OK before saving. You can use `BeforeUpdate` control events to provide earlier feedback on potential problems.

Comment: I made a couple of adjustments now the Time Overlap message box appears but it appears after every time I enter, even if it isn't overlapping time.

`If DCount("*", "[tbl_ActiveOperators]", "[Operator_Start] <= Forms!frm_Job_Details![Operator_End] >= Forms!frm_Job_Details![Operator_Start] Is Null ") > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error:  Times overlap"
    Me.Operator_Start.SetFocus
    Cancel = True
End If
`

Comment: The `DCount` `Criteria` part looks all wrong. Try this: (1) Make your query with literal date values in the Where clause. (2) Once this query is working, add the references to the form controls. (3) Once *that* is working, copy the where clause to the `Criteria` in your `DCount`